# No encuentro solución a este error que me lanza Python usando Django con el método "send_mail" Alguien sabe?

Tags: python, django, mail

**Tengo estas líneas en el archivo << settings.py >>**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND =  "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend" 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = "smpt.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT= 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER="miusuario@ejemplo.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="Ejemplo"
```

**Posteriormente al usar la shell con << python manage.py shell >> ejecuto las siguientes líneas**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail("ASUNTO","CUERPO DE MENSAJE", "miusuario@ejemplo.com",["otrousuario@ejemplo.com"],fail_silently = False)
```

-- Me salta el siguiente error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail_*init*_.py", line 61, in send_mail
return mail.send()
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 284, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 62, in open
self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in **init**
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
self.source_address)
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "C:\Users\Aaronga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

*Ya intente instalar nuevamente python, ya que vi que algunas personas pudieron solucionar el problema, pero en mi caso no se pudo solucionar.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenía el mismo problema hasta que agregue esta última línea de código en mi archivo `settings.py` y el código que usas en `python shell` me funciono a la perfección

```
# Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Test mail]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira un ejemplo de un reset password mio

```
    def reset_password(email, asunto, template_name=None):
        from config.settings.base import EMAIL_HOST_USER
        from django.template.loader import render_to_string
        from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
        from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
        sitio_actual = Site.objects._get_site_by_id(1) # current_site.name
        site_name = sitio_actual.name
        domain = sitio_actual.domain # current_site.domain
        user = get_object_or_404(Usuario,email=email)
        msg_html = render_to_string(template_name, {
            'domain': domain,
            'site_name': site_name,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(str.encode(str(user.id))),
            'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            'protocol': 'https',
            'name': user.first_name + " " + user.last_name,
        })
        msg = EmailMessage(asunto, msg_html,
                           EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])
        msg.content_subtype = "html"
        try:
            msg.send()
        except:`introducir el código aquí`
            print('Error al enviar mensaje al correo %s' % email)
```

De pronto con esto te puedes dar una idea de lo que te falta.